# JQ convert key value pair to array of name,value

Tags: jq

I have following JSON input.  I want to convert this to other json format using JQ.

```json
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":"value3"
}
```

Output format I want

```json
{
    "env": [
        {
            "name": "key1",
            "value": "value1"
        },
        {
            "name": "key2",
            "value": "value2"
        },
        {
            "name": "key3",
            "value": "value3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`to_entries[]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries):

```
{ env: [ to_entries[] | { name: .key, value } ] }
```

Will get the desired output as you can [try in this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-LJqKQSoqYX)